# Remove "Press any key..." from VS C++ Console Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

I've created С++ project using Console Application template, and now I get "Press any key to continue..." message every time when I run my code without debugging (Ctrl + F5). There is no `system("pause")` in my code. How to remove this message?

Comment: That only affects running from Visual Studio without debugging. It does not affect running form command line, from explorer, or from Visual Studio with debugging. Not sure why it does that, but does not seem like it would be a problem in most usage cases.

Comment: Of course, but it was annoying personally for me, and maybe for someone else. It's not convenient for me to run app from anywhere else, or to debug it (i.e. if breakpoints are set)

Comment: It does this so that the window doesn't close as soon as the program exits, which would take away your chance to see the program's output.

Comment: Yes, but if you print to file, there is no need in standard output

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Create an empty project, and include all the sources in this new project. While you're creating empty projects, you'll never have this problem.
2. If it's not possible (the great work was done, for example), there is another way. Close Visual Studio, and then open .vcxproj file with any text editor. Find these lines:

```html
<SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
```

and remove them.
Then search for `_CONSOLE;` in `PreprocessorDefinitions` tag and remove it. Save this file and reopen project. Problem should disappear.